# How can i recompile bundle.js with npm start?

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm trying to understand how NPM start works, i have the following package.json and when i actually make updates in the script it does not automatically recompile the bundle.js so my changes are not reflected. I simply do "mpm start" from the console.

Package.json, part of it

```
{
  "name": "vue-mini-social-network",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A mini-social-network created with VueJS!!",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p --watch"
  }
}
```

webpackage.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './public/js/src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/js/dist/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          'presets': ['env', 'stage-0']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are developing use

```
-> npm run dev
```

you can see the changes happening in development mode.

And after updating script if you want to give that for production

```
-> npm run build
```

Now after above build step use

```
->npm start
```

It will give result with recent build.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of your package.json file is those scripts

```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "nodemon app.js",
      "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
      "build": "webpack -p --watch"
  }
```

Those make shortcut for commands that you want to abstract. Effectively, when you run

```
 npm run dev
```

In reality it runs

```
 webpack -d --watch
```

which is what you want if you you want your webpack to *watch* your changes